# MSAccess - Call Module from onClick

Tags: vba, ms-access

**BACKGROUND**

Develop a series of Make-Table Queries to update and generate a Product Catalog. 
Create a simple user interface for Sales & Marketing to update Product Catalog.

**CODE**

*MODULE*: "updateQuery"

`Public Sub updateQuery()
   Do Something
End Sub`

*Button*: "Update Query" with onClick Event Procedure

`Public Sub updateQuery_Click()
   Call updateQuery
End Sub`

**ERROR**

> Compile Error: Invalid use of Property

**QUESTIONS**

1. What am I missing? I believe the error is being thrown because I am calling a module, but I thought this was the proper approach (using "Call [moduleName]"). Thoughts?

Comment: You need to call the procedure and the module something different.  You can't call a module, you call the subroutine.  Since they have the same name, it is trying to call the module.  Try `Public Sub testSub()` and then `Call testSub`

Comment: Pick one thing to name `updateQuery` and rename everything else.

Comment: Alternatively you could just change it to `Call updateQuery.updateQuery`, but I would recommend the other approach.

Comment: @Comintern - thank you for the solution. Right after posting the question, I figured it actually might be an issue with the name properties, but wasn't able to test prior to stepping out for lunch. Thanks!